# How can I get my tribe back if I die on hardcore?

Tags: ark-survival-evolved

If I die on hardcore, my character resets back to zero, which is fine, but I also lose my tribe and everything in it. If I have a second admin in my tribe, they can just re-invite me. But if I don't have a second admin in my tribe, what can I do? I have a second account, but I seem to be unable to invite an unconscious person (which is what I am when I get on my second account).

How can I get myself back into a tribe on hardcore mode without having another player need to be an admin and re-invite me?

Comment: I haven't tried if it actually works, but one of the loading screen infos says, if the tribe-admin leaves/dies, the next person on the tribe-list becomes the admin.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot invite an unconscious person, that's correct.

What I ended up doing was having a friend with an Xbox One, gameshared ark, and had him bring it over to invite myself with.

If you find some kind soul you can also invite them in, admin them, have them invite your alt, then kick them.

The problem is once your alt becomes a leader, you also have to have someone again to help you get your real account back on since both accounts need to be running at the same time to get invited.